Is there a reliable detection routine for finding out if a given single token can be used as ⟨control sequence⟩ of a ⟨definition⟩?
The following questions are "academical" ones. The questioner does not have a "real life task" in mind which cannot be accomplished without what is asked for.

TeXbook, Chapter 24: Summary of vertical mode says:

⟨definition⟩ → ⟨def⟩⟨control sequence⟩⟨definition text⟩
[...]
Here ⟨control sequence⟩ denotes a token that is either a control sequence or an active character;  [...]

So there are tokens which can be used as ⟨control sequence⟩ for successfully performing a ⟨definition⟩ and there are tokens which cannot be used as ⟨control sequence⟩ for successfully performing a ⟨definition⟩.
Note that it is said that ⟨control sequence⟩ is to be a control sequence token or an active character token. But it is not said that performing a ⟨definition⟩ works out with any possible ⟨control sequence⟩/works out with any possible control sequence token/works out with any possible active character token.
E.g., the token A11, which is not a ⟨control sequence⟩ at all, or frozen-\relax, a control sequence token coming into being via things like \expandafter\expandafter\ifnum0=0\fi, cannot be used as ⟨control sequence⟩ for successfully performing a ⟨definition⟩.
When you try things like
\def A{replacement}

or
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def
\expandafter\expandafter\ifnum0=0\fi{replacement}

you get a TeX-error-message:
! Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \inaccessible 

Is there a reliable detection routine for finding out if a given single token can be used as ⟨control sequence⟩ of a ⟨definition⟩?
In case of presenting or outlining a detection routine, please specify

the TeX engines which it works out with.
whether it works out completely in the processing stage which is called expansion.
whether it would disrupt \romannumeral-expansion/\csname..\endcsname-expansion.
whether it relies on TeX parameters, e.g., \escapechar or \endlinechar, having specific values. If so, please specify the TeX parameters in question.
edge cases/circumstances where it does not work out.

In case such a detection routine is feasible:
(How) Can you crank out (by means of expansion) whether the ⟨control sequence⟩ in question is an active character token?
(Note that a token already defined in terms of \outer can be used as ⟨control sequence⟩ for successfully performing a ⟨definition⟩, but having it passed on as macro argument to routines that take macro arguments is sort of a problem.
However, such a detection routine might be used when defining macros and thus would get its argument passed on from an argument of a macro. Therefore let's assume the focus with the detection-routine is on tokens that are to be processed as arguments of macros and can be assumed not to be \outer.)

I guess \outer makes this near impossible. You can't use any argument grabbing logic at all (so checking whether something is an active character token is impossible, afaik), can only use \futurlet or \let to examine it (or only access the \meaning or \string). In LuaTeX you could use \suppressoutererror to tackle that, but a general mechanism can only work in that or comparable engines, not in pdfTeX or XeTeX, I'm afraid.
